# Length of current Option in Select element allows scrolling

Tags: html, mobile-safari, html-select

I'm not so good with HTML and CSS but currently I have a Form with a Select element inside. It has a number of Options. This is bound to a Vue.js data variable via v-model (though maybe not relevant).

The issue I am seeing is that when the current Option is a long string, it allows the user to scroll the whole form horizontally. It is almost as if it has widened the parent. This only happens when the current selected Option is a long string and also in Sarafi on iOS. If the current Option string is short it doesn't happen nor does it happen in Firefox or Chrome (on Android).

```
   <select
    class="ran-form-input"
    id="detailed_course"
    v-model="detailed_course"
    name="detailed_course"
   >
   <option>This causes a problem because it is a long string and will cause the effects of the parent to be wider.</option>
   <option>This is okay.</option>
   <option>This is also okay.</option>

Since the problem is only on Safari on iOS, I'm not sure how to debug this.
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.